# Is the --target option of the autotool "configure" used for something else than building (cross)compiler?

Tags: gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, autotools

I've made some cross-compiling in the past and I’ve always wondered what the --target option is used for ?

In what kind of situation do you need to have the --host and --target options different ?

please give some examples.

I've read [GNU documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html) but the --target option is still confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for making a [Canadian cross compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#Canadian_Cross).

Comment: And apart building cross compiler ? do you know a case where you use --target for something else ?

Comment: Any time you are going to build object code (libraries, executables) that will run on another platform your'e going to need to use it.

Comment: If I understand correctly the --target option is for Canadian build wich involve 3 plateforms.

Comment: By default (that is for native object code), target is the same as build and host.  For cross compiled object code, build and host are the same, target is different.  For Canadian cross compiled object code, build, host and target are all different.

Comment: I've successfully tested cross compiling with ./configure  --build=i386-linux --host=avr --target=avr and the configure check automatically for avr-gcc as expected